# MongoDB and Authlogic, any gotchas? (mongomapper)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, authlogic, mongomapper

Authlogic, by itself, seems to be too active record centric for MongoDB (specifically mongomapper) as per: http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/issues#issue/15.

However, there's an interesting [authlogic plugin for mongo](http://github.com/cail/authlogic_mongomapper_monkey) that looks pretty awesome, and simple.

Has anyone used this, or have any experience/recommendations for an authlogic mongodb implementation?

Comment: Still looking for anyone else's experience.... I'll leave open for a couple more days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and inplemented it in a spike, changing from restful_authentication to authlogic. The only gotcha I found was needing to add the following code

**/app/models/user.rb**

```
class User
  include MongoMapper::Document
  ...

   def self.quoted_table_name
    "users"
  end
end
```

The quoted_table_name was being requested when creating a new user_session, so I added it and everything was great and happy.

Highly recommend.

**UPDATE**

Once I started using multiple users, the login features stopped working for me. It would log you in if you use the password of the first user, but nothing else mattered.

I switched to this initializer: https://gist.github.com/444888/e8b28196c4f4452a06b89d566a6a245eae1e9d92, which has been nice. I also recommend looking at Devise, which has this straight out of the box for mongomapper.